# Подстановка параметров jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$( ".target" ).change(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
});

mass_goods = '';
$(".select_category").change(function(){
    $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "form1.php",
   data: "id= 'category1'",
   success: function(html){
       var res = JSON.parse(html);
       alert(html); // просто вывод ответа
       alert(res); // распарсим JSON
       alert(res.length);
       mass_goods = res;
       alert(mass_goods[1]); 
       var options = mass_goods;
        $('#select').empty();
        $.each(options, function(i, p) {
        $('#select').append($('<option></option>').val(p).html(p));
});
   }
 });
});
$('name_category').change(function(e) { // select element changed

  });
</script>
```

data: "id= 'category1'", вот нужно чтобы id был равен значению которое берется из $("#cat").val(); вот так не работает data: "id= "+$("#cat").val().

Comment: А alert($("#cat").val()) что показывает?

Comment: Не надо добавлять "не работает" в ответ. Работает. Как Вы узнали, что оно "не работает"? Маленький гномик высунулся из компьютера и сказал: "Не работает!"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
...
data: { id: $(this).val() },
...
```